# Add or Repalce Text in PHP

Tags: php

I am new In PHP.I have js file look like

```
   var sites = [
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal/", duration:9},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
  //Intro detallee
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t1.html", duration:35},
 //CTA
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t2.html", duration:35},

 //Football
  {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/twitter-ligue/", duration:100},


 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 

  //TrailersClub.com
  {url:"http://trailersclub.com/?lang=fr", duration:480},

 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
 //Meteo
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/meteo", duration:12},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-cine/", duration:9},
 //Cine
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/cine/index-t1.html", duration:150},
  //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
   ];
```

I want to add text after var site=[ or any line say at 4 lines using php so how can we add.Here is my code of replacing Text on any line.

```
$lines = array();
foreach( file('source.js') as $line ) {
  if ( 'var site=[' === $line ) {
    array_push($lines, 'test');
  }
  array_push($lines, $line);
}

file_put_contents('source.js', $lines);
```

This code is not working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would append to your file if that's what you're trying to do.

```
<?
$file = "/path/to/file.js";
$lines = file($file);
$lines[] = "test\n";
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
?>
```

If you want to replace the text in that location you can just

```
foreach($lines as $i => $line)
{
   if($line == "text to replace")
      $lines[$i] = "replacement";
}
```

If you want to place a new link at line 4, shift the array to the right and write at array location 3 (`$lines[3]`). Or you can use my function:

```
function array_insert($array, $index, $value) //assumes all keys are ints
{
   for($i=sizeof($array); $i < $index ; $i--)
      $array[$i+1] = $array[$i];
   $array[$index]  = $value;
}
```

Use the function like this if you want to insert "test" at index 4: `array_insert($array, 4, "Test")`

I haven't tested but it should work.

Comment: :file_put_content also save the file automatically?

Comment: file_put_contents will write to the file. (see my edited post) so to answer, yes

Comment: please note that `$line == ` means that it has to match the entire line in the file, not just partial. You would have to use `preg_match()` for that.

Comment: I want to shift  below sites the url only then add text under sites=[] how can we implement it

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, could you be a little more specific

Comment: If I want to add new url at same line then it shift the whole old url below which are already placed.

Comment: Actually there is problem in this code if u see my js file I want to add below the site=[ and above ];but this code shift whole line in +1 line but I want to shift url only then my js file will not work.I think first I search the sites=[ then I shift the line after sites=[ this idea will work or not?

Comment: It would be easier to just readd the `];` to the end of the array.

Comment: :The code yoy given is not shifitng the whole previous url in new line and add new code at that line.Please help me out.